# How can I get all rows where just part of a string repeats?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working in SQL (PostgreSQL) with a dataset where each row is a product the company sold and each column contains some information about the product, like price, size, etc. The problem here is that I have a few types of products: (i) products that are only sold outside my state; (ii) products that are sold only inside the state; (iii) products that may be sold both inside or outside the state; (iv) products that are not specified. To specify where the product may be sold, there is extra strings. We use "-IN" if we sell inside the state and "-OUT" if we sell outside the state. Besides this issue, I can't use only *split_part()* because there might be more than one '-' In other words, I have something like this:

```
product_name        units        price
water-out           5            50
water-out           2            20
water-in            3            21
apple-red-in        7            7
ice-out             4            2
wood-out            12           120
leather             17           6
wood-in             1            10
tuna                5            25
it-br-in            1            2
it-br-out           5            25
```

I want to filter only the products that are sold both inside and outside the state. Products that we have both the possibility of having '-in' and '-out' in the name. I want to get this result:

```
product_name        units        price
water-out           5            50
water-out           2            20
water-in            3            21
wood-out            12           120
wood-in             1            10
it-br-in            1            2
it-br-out           5            25
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use @Gordon's answer but instead of `split_part()` function use `regexp_replace()`: `regexp_replace(t2.name, '-(in|out)$', '') = regexp_replace(t.name, '-(in|out)$', '')`

Comment: @Abelisto it didn't work. I'm trying to understand why

Comment: Be more precise then just "it didn't work". https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8978850b66f4989851a3b2004c16c239

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Assuming that the product name has no hyphens and the only suffixes are "-in" and "-out", then `split_part()` can do this:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where split_part(t2.name, '-', 1) = split_part(t.name, '-', 1) and
                    t2.name <> t.name
             )
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fdd58239c8870384cb598f78eda91b4f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: hmmm that doens't work. Sorry, I should have be more specific on the question. I'll update

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok then. Upvoted and checked as the correct answer